# Php mySql with wamp access denied Error

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

at first Mysql had no problem ( can access db via mySql command line with my password)  but when i run my php file with wamp server ,i receive this Error :

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

.... and after that , not only that my php file raise an error , i get an access denied error trying to access my databases with mySql shell .

i ran these php file with xamp and had no problem , but after switching to wamp all these errors appear , any ideas ?

Comment: Most probably you have 2 instances of MySQL installed. One that comes bundled with WAMP and one other.

Comment: Did you change the password for the root userid? Did you add a new mysql user account, with or without a password. What user/password are you using in your app?

Comment: You may have missed the password for user `root`. Check in your configuration if this is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a new root password within your WAMP environment.  It has a different instance of MySQL to the one in XAMPP, so it won't pick up the same root password.  Change the root password and try connecting again, that should work.